# Angular Reactive forms - share state with children inside loop

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

How can a form inside a child component extend an existing form passed in by a parent component?

Desired effect: if one of the child forms is invalid, the parent form should become invalid as well.

I am using reactive forms. The number of child components can vary.

```
export class AddressFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() addressesForm; // This is the parent form
  @Input() addressData;

  addressForm;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ...
    });

    // Trying to add this to the parent form will break the application (Maximum call stack size exceeded)
    this.addressesForm.push(this.addressesForm);
  }
```

I have made a simplified plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/GymI5CqSACFEvhhz55l1?p=preview.

Comment: You are trying to add addressesForm to itself?

Comment: Whoops. That was it. Just a typo, supposed to be adding addressForm (singular). It's working now... Thanks! Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.